# Which package provides -lGL on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, compiling

I'm trying to install the `pip3` python package `wxpython` which fails due to

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.0.so.0.4.0  gldll_glcmn.o gldll_glx11.o gldll_gtk_glcanvas.o    -L/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib   -Wl,-soname,libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.0.so.0  -pthread         -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lnotify -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpng -lz -ljpeg -ltiff  -lwxregexu-3.0  -pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/version-script -lz -ldl -lm  -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0  -lGL -lGLU -lz -ldl -lm
(cd /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/; rm -f libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0.4.0 libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0 libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so)
(cd /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/; rm -f libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so.0.4.0 libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so.0 libwx_gtk3u_stc-3.0.so)
(cd /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/; rm -f libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0.4.0 libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so.0 libwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0.so)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: -lGL kann nicht gefunden werden
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16113: recipe for target '/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.0.so.0.4.0' failed
make: *** [/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/libwx_gtk3u_gl-3.0.so.0.4.0] Error 1
make: *** Auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse wird gewartet …
(cd /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/; rm -f libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0.4.0 libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so.0 libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so)
g++ -o wxrc wxrc_wxrc.o    -L/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib  -pthread     -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lexpat -lwx_baseu-3.0     -lwxregexu-3.0  -pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/version-script -lz -ldl -lm  -lz -ldl -lm
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/utils/wxrc“ wird verlassen
Error building
ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 1295, in cmd_build_wx
    wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 498, in main
    exitIfError(wxBuilder.build(dir=buildDir, options=args), "Error building")
  File "/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
    raise builder.BuildError(msg)
buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error building
Finished command: build_wx (3m27.477s)
Finished command: build (3m27.478s)
Command '"/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dt7af70p-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-c0hbjq4b/wxpython/
```

`libgl-dev` referes to `libgl1-mesa-dev` which is already installed as well as `libglw1-mesa-dev` which seems the only other possible candidate based on the auto-completion of `sudo apt-get install libgl`.

The installation with `pip` for Python 2.x succeeds.

Comment: Did you install it for the right architecture?

Comment: @SebationStark I have an amd64 system (afaik i386 has been retired anyway). i installed `libgl1-mesa-dev:i386` in order to try whether this is what you could mean, but the error remains the same. I'd appreciate an explanation what you mean be the "right" architecture.

Comment: I meant just that you probably installed the :i386 package by accident or so.

Comment: @SebastianSTark That's an idea worth checking out, but I even installed `libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64` explicitly and it was installed as described in the quesiton.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather two questions. If I take your question literally, an approach would be using `apt-file` to search for packages containing the file you are looking for:

```
$ apt-file search libGL.so
libgl1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libgl1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
libglvnd-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.340.106
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
nvidia-340: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.340.106
primus-libs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
virtualbox-guest-x11: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so
virtualbox-guest-x11: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so.1
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe: /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/libGL.so.1
```

If you haven't got apt-file installed, install it and initialise its database first using:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
```

To check if the linker can actually find the installed library, run this:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

As to why the wxPython build using pip3 is not picking up either of them is a question I can not answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
apt said that `libgl1-mesa-dev` was already installed, but I couldn't find a package in `/var/cache/apt`.

This helped:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libgl1-mesa-dev`

(After this, DO NOT make a `sudo apt autoremove`.)

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

After this compiling worked.

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. The fact that a package can't be found in `/var/cache/apt` doesn't necessarily indicate that it's not properly installed. I had to restart my laptop after this because `nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1` until reboot.